# Java UUID compareTo not working correctly for Type1 UUIDs

Tags: java, sorting, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, timeuuid

While working on a use case where the data needs to be sorted on UUID which are all Type 1 or timebased and generated using Datastax Cassandra Java driver library (UUIDS.timebased()), i found that UUID.compareTo is not sorting some of the UUIDs correctly.
The logic in compareTo is

```
    /**
 * Compares this UUID with the specified UUID.
 *
 * <p> The first of two UUIDs is greater than the second if the most
 * significant field in which the UUIDs differ is greater for the first
 * UUID.
 *
 * @param  val
 *         {@code UUID} to which this {@code UUID} is to be compared
 *
 * @return  -1, 0 or 1 as this {@code UUID} is less than, equal to, or
 *          greater than {@code val}
 *
 */
public int compareTo(UUID val) {
    // The ordering is intentionally set up so that the UUIDs
    // can simply be numerically compared as two numbers
    return (this.mostSigBits < val.mostSigBits ? -1 :
            (this.mostSigBits > val.mostSigBits ? 1 :
             (this.leastSigBits < val.leastSigBits ? -1 :
              (this.leastSigBits > val.leastSigBits ? 1 :
               0))));
}
```

I had the below 2 UUIDs generated using the datastax cassandra driver for java.

```
UUID uuid1 = java.util.UUID.fromString("7fff5ab0-43be-11ea-8fba-0f6f28968a17")
UUID uuid2 = java.util.UUID.fromString("80004510-43be-11ea-8fba-0f6f28968a17")
uuid1.timestamp() //137997224058510000
uuid2.timestamp() //137997224058570000
```

From the above, it is evident that uuid1 is smaller than uuid2, but when we compare them using UUID compareTo method, we get different output. We should get output as -1 as it is supposed to be less than but we get answer as 1 which shows that this uuid1 is greater than uuid2

```
uuid1.compareTo(uuid2) //output - 1
```

On further analysing this, found out that the msb for uuid2 transforms to a negative number where as msb for uuid1 is positive number. Because of this the logic in compareTo is returning the value of 1 instead of -1.

```
u_7fff5ab0 = {UUID@2623} "7fff5ab0-43be-11ea-8fba-0f6f28968a17"
mostSigBits = 9223190274975338986
leastSigBits = -8090136810520933865

u_80004510 = {UUID@2622} "80004510-43be-11ea-8fba-0f6f28968a17"
mostSigBits = -9223296100696452630
leastSigBits = -8090136810520933865
```

Is this behaviour normal with UUID and their comparison with each other ?
If so then how do we handle sorting of such timebased UUIDs?

Thank you

Comment: When a large number becomes negative this means usually that an overflow happened. Not sure though what happens here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69815008/why-is-uuidcompareto-incompatible-with-rfc-4122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that comparing time based UUIDs need special care, [From the docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#startOf-long-):

> Lastly, please note that Cassandra's timeuuid sorting is not compatible with UUID.compareTo(java.util.UUID) and hence the UUID created by this method are not necessarily lower bound for that latter method.

Time based UUIDs should not be compare with the `java.util.UUID#compareTo`. To compare the two time based UUID, you should compare the **time; within these two UUID contains**. you need a custom Utility method implementation or just compare two timesstamps. Here is an example how to do it:

```
// must be timebased UUID
int compareTo(UUID a, UUID b){
   return Long.compare(UUIDs.unixTimestamp(a),UUIDs.unixTimestamp(b));
}
```

To learn more, go through this [DOCS](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response @rahul , the documentation that you referred above is only added for the methods UUIDs.startOf and UUIDs.endOf which provide lowest and highest possible UUIDs for a given timestamp. So the comment makes sense as they are fake UUIDs. But similar comment should have been provided to the method UUIDs.timebased() which actually generates the UUID which fail to sort using java.util.UUID.compareTo. This caused confusion for me.

Comment: Well, actually the thing is you need to understand the ways type 1 UUID is created. Its not necessarily true that the first half of the UUID bits represent the times. That is why cassandra has a different implementation to compare UUID. Please go through this wiki pages to understand how  UUIDs are made. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier. Hopefully you'll get your answer about why compareTo methods are failing for UUID-v1. Carefully check how those 128-bits are filled.

Comment: https://www.uuidtools.com/uuid-versions-explained -> you can also check those. @blankCoder