# Why is UUID#compareTo incompatible with RFC 4122?

Tags: java, comparison, uuid

### Overview

Javas `UUID` class implements `Comparable`. But the order it implements appears to be incompatible with the specificiation given in [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122).

In particular, it is inconsistent with the natural order implied by its string representation (`uuid1.toString().compareTo(uuid2.toString())`), which lines up with the RFC.

---

### Example

You can reproduce and observe the problem by using the following code:

```java
UUID uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
UUID uuid2 = UUID.randomUUID();

Assert.assertEquals(
        Math.signum((int) uuid1.compareTo(uuid2)),
        Math.signum((int) uuid1.toString().compareTo(uuid2.toString())));
```

---

### Details

My main problem with this is that almost all other tools and languages seem to be consistent and compatible with [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122), but Java is not.

In my particular case, I am using **postgresql 13** and order by a column that contains the UUID, e.g. `myColumnd::UUID` or `myColumnd::text` (using `uuid_v4`), but the order I obtain by this differs from the order obtained with Java.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but what Java version are you using?

Comment: How do you want to order UUIDs? By creation time? Random number generator seed? Or node id?

Comment: Javadoc says:  The first of two UUIDs is greater than the second if the most significant field in which the UUIDs differ is greater for the first UUID.

Comment: Please show a concrete case of two actual UUIDs where this issue happens, so that people can debug and also explain you why the order differs.

Comment: You guys are proving my test, I don't need proof for my test, the question stands: why is it different from what a database does? Can't you see the implications with persistence having primary keys (or any other sortable column) using UUIDs?

Comment: @Zabuzard is the test not enough? just run it.

Comment: @PedroBorges I am just trying to make your question better in terms of quality. Requiring people to actually run your code before they can really help you is not really making it easier to help you.

Comment: If your question is "why was it designed like that", you are likely on the wrong site and should ask the actual authors instead. We can only guess what their reasoning might have been and guessing is out of [answer].

Comment: kofemann says it best: "DB usually treat UUIDs as strings, however UUIDs are not strings, but can be represented as those."

Comment: @Zabuzard I get your point, but I ran the test, pasted the result,  and you asked for an example to debug, well debug the test no? it happens for ALL UUIDs, which ever you choose.

Comment: @Zabuzard maybe you're right and this is not a question for Stack Overflow. Do you have any suggestions on where to ask this question?

Comment: JDK-Bug [7025832](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7025832) - Resolution **Won't Fix**  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reason

What you are observing here is a **known bug** which will not be fixed anymore to preserve backwards compatibility.

For details, see [JDK-7025832](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7025832):

> Though the bug is accurate that the `compareTo` implementation is **not consistent with other implementations** the Java `UUID.compareTo()` method **must remain consistent** among versions of Java. The `compareTo()` function is used primarily for sorting and the sort order of UUIDs **must remain stable from version to version of Java**.

---

### Signed comparison

The underlying root problem is that Javas `long` type is a **signed type** but the reference implementation from [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122), and implementations in other tools and languages, do the math with **unsigned types**.

This results in small differences in the outcome of the order, since the point where the numbers over-/underflow is different. E.g. `Long.MAX_NUMBER` is bigger than `LONG.MAX_NUMBER + 1`, but not for their unsigned counterparts.

The issue with Javas implementation was detected too late and now we have to live with this incompatibility.

---

### Implementation Appendix

Here is the *correct* reference implementation from [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122):

```cpp
/* uuid_compare --  Compare two UUID's "lexically" and return */
#define CHECK(f1, f2) if (f1 != f2) return f1 < f2 ? -1 : 1;
int uuid_compare(uuid_t *u1, uuid_t *u2)
{
    int i;

    CHECK(u1->time_low, u2->time_low);
    CHECK(u1->time_mid, u2->time_mid);
    CHECK(u1->time_hi_and_version, u2->time_hi_and_version);
    CHECK(u1->clock_seq_hi_and_reserved, u2->clock_seq_hi_and_reserved);
    CHECK(u1->clock_seq_low, u2->clock_seq_low)

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (u1->node[i] < u2->node[i])
            return -1;
        if (u1->node[i] > u2->node[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
#undef CHECK
```

defined on the struct

```cpp
typedef struct {
    unsigned32  time_low;
    unsigned16  time_mid;
    unsigned16  time_hi_and_version;
    unsigned8   clock_seq_hi_and_reserved;
    unsigned8   clock_seq_low;
    byte        node[6];
} uuid_t;
```

as you see, they compare the nodes, which are `byte`, one by one (in the correct order).

[Javas implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/UUID.java#L513) however is this:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(UUID val) {
    // The ordering is intentionally set up so that the UUIDs
    // can simply be numerically compared as two numbers
    return (this.mostSigBits < val.mostSigBits ? -1 :
            (this.mostSigBits > val.mostSigBits ? 1 :
                (this.leastSigBits < val.leastSigBits ? -1 :
                (this.leastSigBits > val.leastSigBits ? 1 :
                0))));
}
```

based on the two (signed) longs:

```java
private final long mostSigBits;
private final long leastSigBits;
```

Comment: It feels like there are two different issues at stake here, one is the over/underflow you mention that "...results in small differences in the outcome of the order" and another one, the one I am pointing out that happens always. Otherwise how would the order be different for *all* the random UUIDs that I tried?

Comment: Thanks for the amendment on the question by the way, it's more clear now.

Answer (score 8):

Well, in one case you compare UUIDs, in another case two string in lexical order.

According to the Javadoc:

> The first of two UUIDs is greater than the second if the most significant field in which the UUIDs differ is greater for the first UUID.

Comment: Lexical order for hexadecimal string representation == numeric order and even if not, then why would the database do it differently?

Comment: DB usually treat UUIDs as strings, however UUIDs are not strings, but can be represented as those.

Comment: In which case the string is a hexadecimal representation, why would java ordering not match the printed hexadecimal representation since the UUID object and the String object are just two ways of representing the same thing?

Comment: It's almost as obnoxious as having a default comparator for long that is descending and a default for int that is ascending. You can do it, just needed to put it in the java doc right? but why would you?

Comment: To be honest, we use as uuid as pk in db. However we don't expect them to have any particular order.

Comment: @PedroBorges You have to ask the actual authors of this class for **why** they made `UUID#compareTo` incompatible with the order of their string representation.

Comment: @kofemann how are you supposed to paginate results then?

Comment: And by the way PostgreSQL has native support for UUIDs they're not text - https://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/179.html `GUID/UUID is not a text in either PostgreSQL or SQL Server system`

Comment: @Zabuzard It's quite clearly efficiency; the code treats the UUID as two 64-bit (signed) integers, which will be a very quick operation.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Java doesn't have unsigned types, and UUIDs are compared by comparing two pairs of signed `long`s. It's frustrating.

Comment: it is a 10 year old known Bug [7025832](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7025832) :-(

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Your answer is not incorrect but it is the answer to a totally different question. OP is asking **why** Java authors implement `UUID#compareTo` in a way that it is **incompatible with** `String#compareTo` (see the comments). This has nothing to do with the fact that the UUID is represented using two signed longs on first sight. They might as well have implemented `compareTo` as `return toString().compareTo(other.toString());`. Or compare the longs in a way that the outcoming order is compatible with the lexicographic string order by _coincidence_.

Comment: @user16320675 adds the much needed context to this answer. You should have added this and elaborated on it yourself, then people would not downvote the answer.